# R: Delete first and last part of string based on pattern

Tags: r, string, gsub

This string is a ticker for a bond: `OAT 3 25/32 7/17/17`. I want to extract the coupon rate which is 3 25/32 and is read as `3 + 25/32` or `3.78125`. Now I've been trying to delete the date and the name `OAT` with `gsub`, however I've encountered some problems.

This is the code to delete the date:

```
tkr.bond <- 'OAT 3 25/32 7/17/17'
tkr.ptrn <- '[0-9][[:punct:]][0-9][[:punct:]][0-9]'
gsub(tkr.ptrn, "", tkr.bond)
```

However it gets me the same string. When I use `[0-9][[:punct:]][0-9]` in the pattern I manage to delete part of the date, however it also deletes the fraction part of the coupon rate for the bond.

The tricky thing is to find a solution that doesn't involve the pattern of the coupon because the tickers have this form: Name Coupon Date, so, using a specific pattern for the coupon may limit the scope of the solution. For example, if the ticker is this way `OAT 0 7/17/17`, the coupon is zero.

Comment: Just some clarification questions... When you say that it's read as `3 + 25/32` or `3.78125`, are you saying you wish to express it with this form programmatically? Or maybe that it can take those two forms in addition to the first?

Comment: It works both ways for me, once I get `3 25/32` it is simpler to convert it to decimals. Of course, the less code I use to get `3.78125` the better.

Comment: Gotcha. I think there's already some pretty good solutions for you then!

Comment: In the update `OAT 0 7/17/17`, the fraction part is not given.

Comment: Exactly, sometimes it has fractions, other times it doesn't. That's why the first idea I had was to delete the Date and the Name part of the ticker so whatever the Coupon part was I made sure I always captured it.

Comment: @capm It is better to show all the patterns while you post.  Anyway, I updated my second solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
eval(parse(text=sub('[A-Z]+ ([0-9]+ )([0-9/]+) .*', '\\1 + \\2', tkr.bond)))
#[1] 3.78125
```

Or you may need

```
sub('^[A-Z]+ ([^A-Z]+) [^ ]+$', '\\1', tkr.bond)
#[1] "3 25/32"
```

#### Update

```
tkr.bond1 <- c(tkr.bond, 'OAT 0 7/17/17')
v1 <- sub('^[A-Z]+ ([^A-Z]+) [^ ]+$', '\\1', tkr.bond1)
unname(sapply(sub(' ', '+', v1), function(x) eval(parse(text=x))))
#[1] 3.78125 0.00000
```

Or

```
vapply(strsplit(tkr.bond1, ' '), function(x)  
  eval(parse(text= paste(x[-c(1, length(x))], collapse="+"))), 0)
#[1] 3.78125 0.00000
```

Or without the `eval(parse`

```
 vapply(strsplit(gsub('^[^ ]+ | [^ ]+$', '', tkr.bond1), '[ /]'), function(x) {
         x1 <- as.numeric(x)
         sum(x1[1], x1[2]/x1[3], na.rm=TRUE)}, 0)
#[1] 3.78125 0.00000
```

Comment: It works, but help me understand the logic, you use `\\1 + \\2` in the replace argument, how does it works?

Comment: @capm It is the capture. group.  We captured the first numeric element and a space followed i.e. with `([0-9]+ ) using parenthess.  Similary the second capture group is `25/32` and replace the string with those capture groups (`\\1`, and `\\2`)

Comment: Hmmm not sure I see why you're using  the `eval(parse(text=` routine here, if I can call it that?

Comment: @DominicComtois It is based on the expected result in the OP's post (as i understand) to `sum` the numeric elements, but I think your solution may also be his desired result.  Not sure though

Comment: Ok I see... I asked a clarification question, we'll figure it out soon I guess.

Comment: I made some clarifications about the patterns in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace first and last word with an empty string.

```
> tkr.bond <- 'OAT 3 25/32 7/17/17'
> gsub("^\\S+\\s*|\\s*\\S+$", "", tkr.bond)
[1] "3 25/32"
```

**OR**

Use `gsubfn` function in-order to use a function in the replacement part.

```
> gsubfn("^\\S+\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)/(\\d+).*", ~ as.numeric(x) + as.numeric(y)/as.numeric(z), tkr.bond)
[1] "3.78125"
```

**Update:**

```
> tkr.bond1 <- c(tkr.bond, 'OAT 0 7/17/17')
> m <- gsub("^\\S+\\s*|\\s*\\S+$", "", tkr.bond1)
> gsubfn(".+", ~ eval(parse(text=x)), gsub("\\s+", "+", m))
[1] "3.78125" "0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to akrun's answer, using sub with a replacement. How it works: you put your "desired" pattern inside parentheses and leave the rest out (while still putting regex characters to match what's there and that you don't wish to keep). Then when you say `replacement = "\\1"` you indicate that the whole string must be substituted by only what's inside the parentheses.

```
sub(pattern = ".*\\s(\\d\\s\\d+\\/\\d+)\\s.*", replacement = "\\1", x = tkr.bond, perl = TRUE)

# [1] "3 25/32"
```

Then you can change it to numerical:

```
temp <- sub(pattern = ".*\\s(\\d\\s\\d+\\/\\d+)\\s.*", replacement = "\\1", x = tkr.bond, perl = TRUE)

eval(parse(text=sub(" ","+",x = temp)))

# [1] 3.78125
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use strsplit here. Then evaluate components excluding the first and the last. Like this

```
> tickers <- c('OAT 3 25/32 7/17/17', 'OAT 0 7/17/17')
> 
> unlist(lapply(lapply(strsplit(tickers, " "), 
+               function(x) {x[-length(x)][-1]}),
+        function(y) {sum(
+          sapply(y, function (z) {eval(parse(text = z))}) )} ) )
[1] 3.78125 0.00000
```